# Automapper Resolver without source

Tags: c#, automapper

I am currently using a resolver to add category nav links to my base page model as such:

```
public sealed class CategoryNavigationResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, string, ICollection<ProductCategoryModel>>
{
    public ICollection<ProductCategoryModel> Resolve(object source, object destination, string sourceMember, ICollection<ProductCategoryModel> destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        IProductCategoryHandler productCategoryHandler = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IProductCategoryHandler>();
        return productCategoryHandler.GetCategoryNavigation();
    }
}
```

and the mapping:

```
CreateMap<BasePage, BasePageModel>()
    .IncludeBase<BaseEntity, BaseModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductCategoryLinks, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CategoryNavigationResolver, string>(src => src.Alias));
```

However I do not need to pass the alias in as I don't really need a source for the resolver.  Is this the correct way to do this or is there a type of resolver where I do not need to pass in an argument?

I have tried using

```
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ProductCategoryLinks, opt => opt.UseValue(productCategoryHandler.GetCategoryNavigation()));
```

moving the handler into the profile, but that gave me a stack overflow error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I do not need to pass the alias in as I don't really need a
>   source for the resolver. Is this the correct way to do this or is
>   there a type of resolver where I do not need to pass in an argument?

You can ignore passing parameters when using custom value resolvers. But you need to implement `IValueResolver` instead of `IMemberValueResolver`.

Let say you still use the same name for the class implementing `IValueResolver` then you can just use this:

```
opt => opt.ResolveUsing<CategoryNavigationResolver>()
```